# How to debug Xcode SwiftUI Preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Is there a way to debug a crashing SwiftUI Preview? I am trying to learn how to use SwiftData and while my sim app seems to work, many of my Previews keep crashing. Many but not all crashing Views use "preview" SwiftData stored in memory.

Something like a file and line in the code where the crash for the preview happens would be very helpful.

On the web, I found suggestions like:
Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for crash logs from your application.

But it seems difficult to find where the problem happens.

There is no suggestion from the preview as it crashes with "Preview crashed" icon and nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Should get a popup with something like "Report", if you click on report you can then see the full crash log. You can then hit "Cancel" so you dont actually send the report to Apple

Comment: When it crashes like this, there is no popup or anything.